# How to get artwork_url based on trackid in thml

Tags: javascript, html, artwork

I would like to add thumbnail in my html with trackid and clicking on the thumbnail image will open modelbox to play video.

on the html page I have only track id info.

So how can I display thumb image on basic html page?

```js
SC.get('/tracks/726040417', function(sound) {
    console.log(sound.artwork_url);
});
```

i am using something like above but its giving SC undefied error.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly `SC` is?

Comment: This looks like SoundCloud API https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks which also contains information on changing which size image to use.